# Is it possible and how to have Scala par consume threads from a thread pool?

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool, thread-local

In Scala 2.11.8 I'm using `par` to parallelize a large and lengthy `foreach`. I'm also trying to optimize the code to avoid creating new instances of an object each time and therefore I need to use `DynamicVariable`. However, I noticed that still there are many instances of this class created which leads me to think that `par` is always spanning new threads rather than reusing them. Thus the OP how to have par consume threads from a pool of limited reusable threads? is this possible?

```
for (k <- 0 until 5) {
    // avoid creating instances of PearsonsIncCorr
    val inc = new DynamicVariable[PearsonsIncCorr](new PearsonsIncCorr)
    elems.par foreach { pair => // <======= Here I'd like par to consume from a Thread pool 
      inc.withValue(new PearsonsIncCorr) {
        inc.reset(...)
        // compute incremental correlation
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[par](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala#L164) has the default **thread pool**, that's the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global`, this thread pool is depended by the [processors](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9acab45aeeadef2f63da69faf81465cc15599789/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L91).

So the `par` will not always **spawn** new thread for **loop**.

and if you need to create custom [TaskSupport](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala#L201), you can do it like:

```
   val pc = mutable.ParArray(1, 2, 3)
   pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
      new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(2))
   }}}
   pc.foreach(println)
```